# How control output redirection in R via function parameter?

Tags: r

I try to redirect cat() output depending on a function parameter as shown below. I am not sure how to avoid an overflow by recursive reference or a stack overflow.

```
testme1 = function(cat=cat) {
cat("This is testme1\n")
}

testme2 = function(cat=function(...){cat(...)}) {
cat("This is testme2\n")
}

> testme1()                           # Error in testme1() : 
                                      # promise evaluation     läuft bereits: rekursive Referenz auf das Standardargument oder frühere Fehler?
> testme1(cat=cat)                    # works
> testme1(cat=function(...)cat(file="huhu.txt",...)) # works

> testme2()                           # Error: protect(): protection stack overflow
> testme2(cat=cat)                    # works
> testme2(cat=function(...)cat(file="huhu.txt",...)) # works
```

Comment: I've read this code several times now, and I can't for the life of me figure out what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe it would help if you described (in words) what you're aiming for.

Comment: @Egus try `testme1 = function(cat=base::cat) {...}`

Comment: @Matthew Plourde:  Thanks a lot, works!

Comment: @joran: My intention was to provide a way to redirect cat output (of existing code) e.g. to file or to a GUI widget - without having to modify the existing code significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using capture.output() ? 
e.g.

```
testme = function() {
  cat("This is testme\n")
}
testme()

output <- capture.output(testme())
output
```

Comment: Yes. capture.output() does not seem to support logging. Suppose, testme() calls cat() twice like this:  
`testme = function() {  
      cat("This is testme: part 1\n"); flush.console();  
      readline(prompt = "hit return");  
      cat("This is testme: part 2\n"); flush.console();  
    }`  
capture.output() provides both outputs after testme() is finished. Therefore, I could not use it, e.g., for redirection to a log window widget.

Comment: I'm sure to understand. What would you like to get in that case ? And what sort of custom cat function will get what you want ?

Comment: As an example, for calling a worker function that outputs to a log window widget like this: `workerFunc(cat = function(...){
zz <- textConnection("foo", "w"); cat(file=zz,...); close(zz); insert(gtext.obj, foo)})`
or calling the same worker function that outputs to a log file like this: `workerFunc(cat = function(...)cat(file="huhu.txt",...))`

Comment: but in that case the content of your file will be exactly the output of capture.output, so what is the problem ?

Comment: You are right: but the timing is different. capture.output() writes everything collected in the end. I cannot watch the individual log messages - so it cannot be used for a log window within a GUI. Of course, output to a file is not problematic, here.

Comment: OK I understand. capture.output has a file argument to control where the output goes, cf ?capture.output. I still think it may answer your problem.